# Unable to scrape website with form using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape the the following website listed below.  I tried to do this by using `rvest` with the code below.

My attempt was to try to replicate the `PUT` that I found in Google Chrome for the Download button.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I am getting the error listed in my `reprex`.

```r
  library(httr)
  library(rvest)
  library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

  
  
  url <- "https://nfc.shgn.com/adp/baseball"
  pgsession <- session(url)
  
  pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]

  filled_form <- html_form_set(pgform,
                            team_id = "0", from_date = "2020-10-01", to_date = "2021-02-19", num_teams = "0",
                            draft_type = "0", sport = "baseball", position = "",
                            league_teams = "0" )
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'team_id'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'from_date'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'to_date'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'num_teams'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'draft_type'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'sport'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'position'.
#> Warning: Setting value of hidden field 'league_teams'.
  
  session_submit(x = pgsession, form = filled_form)
#> Error: `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to scrape that table, you can do it easily with `rvest` and `purrr` by using the URL that the "Print" button takes you to.

Although you can't use `html_table`, it is straightforward to extract the cells as a dataframe using `purrr::map_df`:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

pgtab <- read_html("https://nfc.shgn.com/adp.data.php") %>%  #destination of Print button
  html_nodes("tr") %>%                 #returns a list of row nodes
  map_df(~html_nodes(., "td") %>%      #returns a list of cell nodes for each row
           html_text() %>%             #extract text
           str_trim() %>%              #remove whitespace
           set_names("Rank","Player","Team","Position","ADP","MinPick",
                     "MaxPick","Diff","Picks","Team2","PickBid"))

head(pgtab)

# A tibble: 6 x 11
  Rank  Player             Team  Position ADP   MinPick MaxPick Diff  Picks Team2 PickBid
  <chr> <chr>              <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 1     Ronald Acuna Jr.   ATL   OF       1.69  1       6       ""    332   ""    ""     
2 2     Fernando Tatis Jr. SD    SS       2.57  1       7       ""    332   ""    ""     
3 3     Mookie Betts       LAD   OF       3.53  1       9       ""    332   ""    ""     
4 4     Juan Soto          WAS   OF       3.98  1       10      ""    332   ""    ""     
5 5     Mike Trout         LAA   OF       6.08  1       11      ""    332   ""    ""     
6 6     Gerrit Cole        NYY   P        6.50  1       15      ""    332   ""    ""
```

You can also set the form parameters and do this, although you'll have to check whether it makes a difference.  Here is one way...

```
url <- "https://nfc.shgn.com/adp/baseball"
pgsession <- html_session(url)

pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[2]]

filled_form <-set_values(pgform,
                         team_id = "0", from_date = "2020-10-01", to_date = "2021-02-19", num_teams = "0",
                         draft_type = "0", sport = "baseball", position = "",
                         league_teams = "0" )

filled_form$url <- "https://nfc.shgn.com/adp.data.php" #error if this is left blank

pgsession <- submit_form(pgsession, filled_form, submit = "printerFriendly")

pgtab <- pgsession %>% read_html() %>% #code as per previous answer above
  html_nodes("tr") %>% 
  map_df(~html_nodes(., "td") %>% 
           html_text() %>% 
           str_trim() %>% 
           set_names("Rank","Player","Team","Position","ADP","MinPick",
                     "MaxPick","Diff","Picks","Team2","PickBid"))
```

Comment: Good spot especially as only works because javascript doesn't run!

Comment: Thanks!  This works!  A few questions, what would an additional option look like to allow for the query fields to be chosen from the form I listed?  Why do you use map_df for the td nodes, but not the tr ones?  How would I extract data-playerid data for each row as well?

Comment: @Jazzmatazz I'll have a look at whether the form fields can be changed, although I think they are just filters, so would probably just give you a subset of this whole table. I think to get the detailed player data you would need to use rselenium. `html_nodes` produces a list, and to retain the list structure it is necessary to use `map` to iterate through it and produce a nested list of cells for each row. `map_df` coerces the nested list to a dataframe (as long as you set some names). This is just the neatest way of getting it into a dataframe.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz I've added an example of setting the form values in the answer above.

Comment: I am still getting the error "Error: `form` doesn't contain a `action` attribute" after running your pgsession code above.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz Strange - it works fine for me. Not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: @AndrewGustar what OS are you on?  I actually just tried on Mac and it works fine, but it doesn't work on my Windows laptop.

Comment: @Jazzmatazz I'm on Windows 10, so it's not that! I think I've got the latest versions of R, rvest, etc.  Very odd.

Comment: Now the code isn't working on my Mac either.  Any way we can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution using `rSelenium` for downloadin the tsv.file to a given folder.
After that, easy peasy...

```
library( RSelenium )
library( rvest )
library( xml2 )
library( data.table )

#setup download file + location
filename <- "ADP.tsv"
download_location <- file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"), "Downloads")

#create extra cpabilities, so the browser(firefox) does not display an save-as dialog 
# when downloading the tsv file
eCaps <- makeFirefoxProfile( list( "browser.download.dir" = download_location,
                                   "browser.download.folderList" = 2, 
                                   "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk" = "text/tab-separated-values",
                                   "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting" = FALSE ) )
#setup driver (using the firefox profile created before), client and server
driver <- rsDriver( browser = "firefox", port = 4545L, extraCapabilities = eCaps, verbose = FALSE )
server <- driver$server
browser <- driver$client

#goto url in browser
browser$navigate( "https://nfc.shgn.com/adp/baseball" )
#get 
button_dl <- list()
#while no buttons found (site not loaded), try to load the download-button
while ( length( button_dl ) == 0 ) {
  button_dl <- browser$findElements(using = "name", "download" )
}
#now click the button and wait for the file to show up in the download_location
button_dl[[1]]$clickElement()
#wait for download to complete
Sys.sleep(5)
#check if file is loaded
if ( file.exists( paste( download_location, filename, sep = "/" ) ) ) {
  #load the file
  DT <- data.table::fread( paste( download_location, filename, sep = "/" ) )
}
#close everything down properly
browser$close()
server$stop()

head(DT)
#    Rank              Player Team Position(s)  ADP Min Pick Max Pick Difference # Picks Team Team Pick
# 1:    1   Acuna Jr., Ronald  ATL          OF 1.68        1        6         NA     323   NA        NA
# 2:    2 Tatis Jr., Fernando   SD          SS 2.58        1        7         NA     323   NA        NA
# 3:    3       Betts, Mookie  LAD          OF 3.50        1        9         NA     323   NA        NA
# 4:    4          Soto, Juan  WAS          OF 3.98        1       10         NA     323   NA        NA
# 5:    5         Trout, Mike  LAA          OF 6.06        1       11         NA     323   NA        NA
# 6:    6        Cole, Gerrit  NYY           P 6.52        1       15         NA     323   NA        NA
```

Comment: I've never used RSelenium before.  Can you point me to a resource that helps me set up the firefox profile?  I am getting an error when I run rsDriver.

Comment: I recommend following some basic selenium totorials first...