# Download & decompress JSON file in R using curl or RCurl

Tags: r, json, curl, rcurl

I have the following bash script to download & decompress a JSON file:

```
#!/bin/sh -ex

# Ensure data directory (or a link) exists.
test -e results || mkdir results

# Download and decompress data.
curl -u $GISAID_USERNAME:$GISAID_PASSWORD --retry 4 \
  https://www.epicov.org/epi3/3p/$GISAID_FEED/export/provision.json.xz \
  | xz -d -T8 > results/gisaid.json
```

Ideally I would like to have an R function to download & decompress this file in a given directory, with the environment variables above $GISAID_USERNAME, $GISAID_PASSWORD & $GISAID_FEED passed as arguments. Would anyone know how to accomplish this, e.g. using package `curl` or `RCurl`? (It would also be OK not to decompress it and leave it as .json.xz, as I would be reading the file later using

```
library(jsonlite)
GISAID_json <- jsonlite::stream_in(gzfile(".//data//GISAID_json//provision.json.xz"))
```

Comment: since tag is also R: In my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66320754/6356278) is a way to download files to a specific location using Rselenium.

Comment: is there a publicly available json.gz file (url) you can give so we can try on that dummy file

Comment: @stevec can't share it publicly, but send me an email at tom.wenseleers@kuleuven.be and I can give you some more details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
library(curl)
library(glue)

custom_curl <- function(user, pass, feed, dest) {
  custom_handle <- curl::new_handle()
  curl::handle_setopt(
    custom_handle,
    username = user,
    password = pass
  )
  
  url <- glue::glue(
    "https://www.epicov.org/epi3/3p/{feed}/export/provision.json.xz"
  )
  
  curl::curl_download(url, dest, handle = custom_handle)
}

custom_curl('my_user', 'xxxxxx', 'feed1', 'dest/filename.json.xz')
```

As I can't test in the real files and url, I'm not sure if little tinkering in the function is needed, but at least is a starter point for you.

Comment: Many thanks for that! Works perfectly - didn't even have to tinker with anything!

Answer (score 1):

Does executing your terminal commands in R using the `system` function already help you?

Put your terminal call into `system()` and it should execute and create your file. Afterwards read in the file. Of course you would have to replace the $GISAID_USERNAME, $GISAID_PASSWORD with your actual information. If the login information or the url should be flexible, you can put together a string beforehand, since `system()` expects a string with the command to execute.

```
system("curl -u $GISAID_USERNAME:$GISAID_PASSWORD --retry 4 \
https://www.epicov.org/epi3/3p/$GISAID_FEED/export/provision.json.xz \
| xz -d -T8 > results/gisaid.json")
```

Afterwards just read in the (hopefully) created file.

Couldn't test with your setup, but for me e.g. this small example successfully creates a  file:

```
system("curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SteffenMoritz/imputeTS/master/pkgdown/favicon/favicon.ico > /Users/Steve/Downloads/x.ico")
```

Comment: Yes had thought of that, but whether this would work would heavily depend on one's computer setup & OS etc. In the end I went with the pure R solution below using curl, which worked perfectly... But thanks anyway!